# Twig - Showing/Hiding Element Based Upon Date

Tags: javascript, dynamic, twig

I am looking to customize a Twig template by making the display of an element (i.e. a url link) sensitive to the current date.  As I'm fairly new to Twig, would Twig have any in-house ways to facilitate this, or would I most likely utilize some Javascript to achieve this?

Thanks for any leads.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `date`-filter and the special keyword `NOW` to achieve this

```
{% if "NOW"|date('U') > '2018-06-10'|date('U') %}
    Show this
{% endif %}

{% if "NOW"|date('U') > '2029-06-10'|date('U') %}
    Don't show this
{% endif %}
```

---

*do note that you could just pass the date as a `DateTime` to your template to avoid the static code in the template`*